# whats wrong on this cod? update mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

This is part of my new script (PHP + MySQL). I can echo `$price_exchange_update` on output, so it's not empty or uncompilable data for MySQL (varchar-255).

this is worked cod:

```
mysqli_query($rate_db,"UPDATE rate_prices SET 
                       price_exchange_update = 'test 36'
                       WHERE ID='1'");
```

But if I use this:

```
mysqli_query($rate_db,"UPDATE rate_prices SET 
                       price_exchange_update = '$price_exchange_update'
                       WHERE ID='1'");
```

also this:

```
mysqli_query($rate_db,"UPDATE rate_prices SET 
                       price_exchange_update = ".$price_exchange_update."
                       WHERE ID='1'");
```

both of them not work. where am I wrong?

---- Update

I use [simplehtmldom](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/) to grab date & time from other page. My variable is this:

```
$price_exchange_update = $html->find("span[id=updateTime]", 0);

echo $price_exchange_update;
```

and out put is: `شنبه ۲۴ خرداد  ۱۲:۳۸`

I tested, if I use

```
mysqli_query($rate_db,"UPDATE rate_prices SET 
                       price_exchange_update = 'شنبه ۲۴ خرداد ۱۲:۳۸'
                       WHERE ID='1'");
```

It's worked. but when I try to update from the variable, it's not work.

Comment: one reason could be `$price_exchange_update` contains a single quote in the value.

Comment: Use prepared statements. See [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)

Comment: What does $price_exchange_update contain?

Comment: Thanks for attention, No.outputs somthing like this `شنبه ۲۴ خرداد  ۱۲:۳۸ `. this is Persian time and date.

Comment: Check your character encoding on MySQL. And from the sounds of it, you might want to use a `TIMESTAMP` field, and use numbers instead of VARCHAR

Comment: before executing the query check whether you get the value in variable...echo it..

Comment: I update my question with more info.

Comment: try like this $price_exchange_update2  = mysqli_real_escape_string($rate_db, $price_exchange_update);

Comment: I echo `$price_exchange_update2`, it's not diffident with `$price_exchange_update`. But it's work ! so thanks.